# decimal digit grouping delimiters

Tags: notation, convention

I feel a bit silly having to ask this but I just can't seem to find any resources that give an answer to this.

When dealing with decimal values that have a large number of digits to the right of the decimal point, is there any sort of convention regarding grouping delimiters? It's not of dire importance for my project but it would definitely improve readability since I am dealing with 100 millionths, billionths, etc.

If there is, would grouping be in the same manner of whole numbers (after 100th, 100,000th, etc eg. 1.00,000,01) or after 1000th, 1,000,000th (eg. 1.000,000,1).

Seems like such a trivial question but I really can't find any resources specifying this.

Comment: I've never personally seen that done.